# Load Widget's load message not displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

Scenario:
I want to transition from a page to a second page by clicking a button, and I want a loading message to be displayed on the second page from the 'transition' event triggers until the 'show' events triggers.

Constraints:
1. I'm using JQM 1.4.2.
2. The tasks to be performed once the 'transition' event triggers are high time-demanding tasks (this is why I'm interested in showing a loading message) and they aren't AJAX-related calls.

Problems:
The loading message isn't appearing on the page when it is requested to appear once the 'transition' event triggers, as well as neither it is when requested once the 'show' event triggers.

Code:

```
//Show or hide the load message
function showLoader(msgText) {
    $.mobile.loading('show', {text : msgText, textVisible : true, theme : 'a'});
}

function hideLoader() {
    $.mobile.loading('hide');
} 

//'transition' event
$(document).on("pagecontainertransition", function(event, data) {
    console.log("#document:pagecontainer_transition triggered ["       
    $(data.toPage).attr("id") + "]");

    switch ($(data.toPage).attr("id")) {
        case "p1":
             break;
        case "p2":
             onTransition_p2();
             break;
        default:
    }
});

function onTransition_p2() {
    //perform long-time-consuming activity1
    console.log("onTransition_p2():starting activity 1...");
    showLoader("starting activity 1...");
    // activity 1   
    hideLoader();
    console.log("setTimeout1():activity 1 done");

    //perform long-time-consuming activity2
    console.log("onTransition_p2():starting activity 2...");
    showLoader("starting activity 2...");
    hideLoader();
    console.log("setTimeout2():activity 2 done");
 }
```

I'd really appreciate if anyone could tell me why the 'showLoader' calls aren't causing the  load messages to be displayed, and how I should tackle this task.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After having spent some time researching on my own and asking for help in right forums, I'd like to share the solution I've been provided with.

First of all, we must bear in mind that browsers don't render during event callbacks, so any request to show a loading message within the event callback won't be carried out until the callback has finished, which could be too late, specially if after having made a request to show a loading message on the page we try to run some time-consuming activities.

So, it's important to launch the request to show the loading message and, inmediately, place the time-consuming activities in the callback function required in a 'setTimeout()' call.
This way, after having requested the loading message to appear on the page, the 'setTimeout()' is carried out, and then the 'transition'-event-related callback finishes. Once it's finished, the browser has a chance to render and then, the time-consuming activities within the 'setTimeout()' callback functions are carried out.

Here is the working code:

```
function onTransition_p2(event) {

  showLoader("starting activity1...");
  setTimeout(function() {
    //time-consuming activity1
    hideLoader();
    showLoader("starting activity2...");
    setTimeout(function() {            
        //time-consuming activity2
        hideLoader();
    }, 0);        
  }, 0);
}
```

I'd also like to suggest a reading of the post where the solution has been provided since the author of the solution doesn't suggest performing time-consuming activities in one lump as they could make UI thread be locked-up until these tasks complete.

https://forum.jquery.com/topic/loader-widget-s-loading-message-not-displayed-in-jqm1-4-2